Why use "connection: local" with "delegate_to: localhost"?
Is there any advantage of using "connection: local" in addition to "delegate_to: localhost"?
While reviewing my merge request, a colleague said, that I should always use "connection: local" in addition to "delegate_to: localhost". Is that a good idea? Why would I need to do that?
Edit: The colleague said that "delegate_to: localhost" changes the destination of the SSH connection and "connection: local" uses a direct/local connection on the host instead of remote connection with ssh. Both together remove an unnecessary layer for locally executed tasks and speed-up the task a bit. Is that true?

Why would I need to do that? <= there's actually no reason I can think of. Except maybe if you explicitly defined localhost with an other connection plugin in your inventory and want to make sure you are using a local connection. But you should usually rely on implicit localhost

Your colleague is incorrect. delegate_to: localhost uses the delegate host's connection settings, not the current play host's. localhost is normally configured to use the local connection plugin, and if it's not there's hopefully a good reason someone made that change and you shouldn't second-guess it at the task level. (If there's not a good reason, you should fix it comprehensively at the inventory level instead of constantly working around it.)

Thanks @Zeitounator and @flowerysong. You are both correct.
Using the implicit localhost is indeed the way to go. My colleague had localhost explicitly in the inventory and was glad for the advice and removed it.
My understanding of Ansible improved and now I can help more than before.

localhost is normally configured to use the local connection plugin, and if it's not there's hopefully a good reason someone made that change and you shouldn't second-guess it at the task level.

That was a - now fixed - problem.
